# How do I set up user authentication using devise and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to get user authentication with devise working, and failing.

I tried following the steps in the [RailsGirls article](http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise/), but after creating the simple new project, adding the `gem 'devise'` and running `bundle install`, but when I run `rails generate devise:install` I get a screenful of errors starting

```
Error:Get available generators script executes with errors:
Error:C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
```

Has anybody any idea what I might be doing wrong? (I tried using the instructions in the devise wiki, but I couldn't get it working that way either).

Comment: Have you created User model already?

Comment: Rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: What do you get with `rails -v` run in the console in the project root level?

Comment: @PavelVolzhin Yes, I already have a user model

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes, Rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 1.9.3. I followed the instructions in Agile Web Development with Rails 4, although I don't know how that gave me Rails 4.0.2...

Comment: Add please config/routes.rb and app/models/user.rb to your first post.

Comment: Getting this EXACT error without adding `gem 'devise'` to my gem file

Answer (score 1):

I just ran to this same problem today, it's because you tried to generate the model before you tried to install devise it self

Stash ( or remove ) the changes for the user model and any migration file, then run this

```
rails generate devise:install
```

after that unstash and apply the migration, it should work just fine.