# Problems with Rails Girls Guides's Adding Authentication with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm very new to Rails, and I'm trying to build a user authentication system with 'devise', but I am failing. I'm following Rails Girls Guides's [tutorial](http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise/) on adding authentication using the gem 'devise'. Once I got to step 5, which is to set up the User model, I received this error after running `rake db:migrate`

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x007fd3397a7448>
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.0.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:420:in `ensure in with_devise_exclusive_scope'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.0.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:420:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.0.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:233:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.0.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:336:in `block in devise_scope'
```

Has anyone solved this error? I've looked at all solutions such as [not generating user model before installing devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940567/how-do-i-set-up-user-authentication-using-devise-and-rails-4), [running bundle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512937/ruby-gem-devise-error-after-generating-model?rq=1), [running rails g devise:install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753727/rails4-and-devise-nomethod-error?rq=1), and more. Nothing has worked so far when I'm trying to use devise for Rails 4.0.

Also, does anyone have recommendations on what tutorials I can follow to build an authentication system? I've tried a lot so far, and none has worked.

Comment: please do `rails -v` to check if you are using rails 4.0 or 4.2. This looks to be just affecting rails 4.2 as seen here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3158

Comment: My version is 4.2, so I believe you are correct to suspect this. How do I change my rails version?

Comment: This issue happens to be already fixed on devise. Can you check what version of devise you are using? You can run this to check it `bundle list | grep devise`

Comment: I'm using devise 3.4.1

Comment: no you are not. I just realised the devise version is at the error backtrace you posted :) `ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.0.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be a know bug with prior 3.4.0 devise.

Upgrading it should make this error go away.

To do that edit your `Gemfile` where you have `gem "devise" <might have some other stuff in front>` and change it to `gem "devise", '~> 3.4.1'`

then run `bundle update devise` and you are done.